# Delphi Shared Module for Apache Runs Out of Memory

Tags: delphi, apache2, out-of-memory, delphi-2010, fastmm

I hope someone will shed some lights on issue I am having.

I am writing an Apache shared object module that acts as a server for my app.  Client or multiple Clients make SOAP request to this module, module talks to database and returns SOAP responses to client(s).
Task Manager shows httpd processes (incoming requests from clients) in Task Manager using about 35000K but every once in a while, one of httpd processes will grow in memory/CPU usage and over time reach the cap of 2GB, and then it will crash.  Server reports "Internal Server 500" error in this case. (screenshot added)

[image]

I use FastMM to check for memory leaks and it does produce log but there is no memory leaks reported.  To make sure I use FastMM properly, I introduced memory leaks and FastMM will log it.  So, my assumption is that I do not have memory leak but that somehow memory gets consumed until 2GB threshold is reached and not released until I manually restart Apache.

Then I started taking snapshots using FastMM's LogMemoryManagerStateToFile call to create memory snapshot at the time of call. LogMemoryManagerStateToFile creates file with following information but I dont understand how is it helpful to me other than telling me that for example 8320 calls to UnicodeString allocated 676512 bytes.
Which of these are not released properly?
Note that this information is shortened version of created file and it is just for one single method call.  There could be many calls that occur to different methods:

```
FastMM State Capture:
---------------------

1793K Allocated
7165K Overhead
20% Efficiency

Usage Detail:
676512 bytes: UnicodeString x 8320
152576 bytes: TTMQuery x 256
144312 bytes: TParam x 1718
134100 bytes: TDBQuery x 225
107444 bytes: Unknown x 1439
88368 bytes: TSDStringList x 1052
82320 bytes: TStringList x 980
80000 bytes: TList x 4000
53640 bytes: TTMStoredProc x 90
47964 bytes: TFieldList x 571
47964 bytes: TFieldDefList x 571
41112 bytes: TFields x 1142
38828 bytes: TFieldDefs x 571
20664 bytes: TParams x 574
...
...
...
4 bytes: TChunktIME x 1
4 bytes: TChunkpHYs x 1
4 bytes: TChunkgAMA x 1

Additional Information:
-----------------------
Finalizing MyMethodName
```

How is this data helpful to figure out where memory is being consumed so much in terms of locating it in code and fixing it?

Much appreciated,

Comment: Your module is consuming too much memory. But noone can give you any reason without knowing what the module is doing (source). Until now this question is off topic

Comment: At which point to you check for memory leaks? If you only check at the end, maybe all objects already have been freed. FastMM4 also allows to take snapshots during execution, which helps to detect runtime-only leaks.

Comment: @ Sir Rufo  How do I figure out where/why is it using to much memory?  The module is serving SOAP request from thin clinet, so every request from client (say to get list of items) is handled by the module.  Client calls Module (Server) calls database to get results and then returns the result to the client.  Do I need to provide info in new request or can just continue here?  Thanks,

Comment: @mjn Thank you.  First I tried reproducing the memory leak report the way I always did as per FastMM guides.  Add reference to FastMM4 at the top of using clause in project, add necessary files, set FastMMOptions.inc.  Just as I always did to produce memory leak file.  Again, if I intentionally introduce the leak, it will catch it.  But otherwise, no leak.  I tried to use the snapshot option (LogMemoryManagerStateToFile) but that overwrites data in the file each time it is called instead of appending it.  So I end up only with "last" snapshot.

Comment: This is correct, but at the start of the file you will see the objects with the highest instance count, and if these values always increase / never decrease over time, this is a run time leak. I also use a text viewer which automatically refreshes to watch changes in the file.

Comment: @mjn has the right idea. You should take periodic snapshots, so that when memory usage is rising sharply, you can see what's using the memory.  It's not a "leak" if it de-allocates when done. I had one like that where the program (produces an extract from a complex database query) stuffed the whole extract into a series of stringlists, which were properly de-allocated at the end. The problem occurs when you have so much data that these stringlists grow huge, and cripple the system.  The "intent to free at the end" is little consolation when you're approaching 2 GB.

Comment: @mjn Hi mjn and thank you for your reply.  I have updated my question and posted an example of what gets created by FastMM call to LogMemoryManagerStateToFile.  I have this call at many places in my app and each is producing same output like above with 0K Allocated, 0K Overhead and 100% Efficiency.  I also notice that Usage Detail is always empty.

Comment: @SirRufo  I can not provide you with a code example since I dont know where it is consuming so much memory. If you read my post, you will see that it is not just a simple method call. I am looking for recommendations, tools to investigate my problem so I can post the example that is the problem here once I figure out where it is. There is nothing that can be improved. As much as I appreciate your help, please don't just put my questions on hold. I am sure some other users have had similar or same issue and someone could help me. Much appreciated.

Comment: @SirRufo Hope the new updated post passes the requirements.  I am exploring here uncharted waters that is the reason I can not provide you more info.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @d.b `Usage detail is always empty' - but not in your example above. It starts with "676512 bytes: UnicodeString x 8320". Is the example taken from the real application?